# R - Bulk column value replacement

Tags: r

In R I have a data.frame and I'd like to do a bulk update.

My table looks like

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
A      123   456
A      789   012
B      345   678
B      789   012
```

I want to scan over the table and replace `A` with `"Apple"` and `B` with `"Banana"`

In my case, the list of replacements is quite long (~30 items) so I have them both in lists like:

```
old<-c('A','B')
new<-c('Apple','Banana')
```

Comment: You could still mark one of these as an answer you know.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I ended up using mapvalues() form plyr which worked a tread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like working with named vectors:

```
   df <- data.frame(Col1=c('A','A','B','B'), 
                    Col2=c(123,789,345,789), 
                    Col3=c(456,012,678,012))
oldv <- c('A','B')
newv <- c('Apple','Banana')
names(newv) <- oldv
df$Col1 <- newv[ df$Col1 ]
```

yields

```
  > df
    Col1 Col2 Col3
1  Apple  123  456
2  Apple  789   12
3 Banana  345  678
4 Banana  789   12
```

Comment: Yes, made it to 1800 :)

Comment: I _knew_ I was forgetting something like that. It's even generalizable to multidimensional situations.

Comment: I have used this on like 4 questions in the last few weeks after I picked it up last month in the first chapter of Hadley's Advanced R book... I guess it is not that well known.

Comment: I'm quite sure I have used it on SO before, and I know that I learned it on rhelp

Comment: Beware that `df$Col1` is a factor in this example - you need `newv[ as.character(df$Col1) ]` to be safe. E.g., try it with `levels(df$Col1) <- c("B","A")` and see how `newv[df$Col1]` and `newv[as.character(df$Col1)]` give differing results

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `lookup()` from `qdapTools`:

```
ref <- data.frame(old = c("A", "B"),
                  new = c("Apple", "Banana"))

library(qdapTools)
df$Col1 <- lookup(df, ref)
```

Alternatively, you could use the `%l%` operator if you prefer the syntax:

```
df$Col1 <- df %l% ref
```

Or using base R:

```
df$Col1 <- ref$new[match(df$Col1, ref$old)]
```

Which gives:

```
#    Col1 Col2 Col3
#1  Apple  123  456
#2  Apple  789   12
#3 Banana  345  678
#4 Banana  789   12
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit hamfisted since I try to avoid for-loops on aesthetic grounds:

```
dat$Col1 <- as.character(dat$Col1)
for ( i in seq_along(old) ) {dat$Col1 [ dat$Col1 == old[i] ] <- new[i] }

> dat
    Col1 Col2 Col3
1  Apple  123  456
2  Apple  789   12
3 Banana  345  678
4 Banana  789   12
```